# Beginner using Rails 3.0.7, Heroku, Compass (Blueprint)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, compass-sass

Problem: I would like my development and production (Heroku) environments to reference my stylesheets from a single location (e.g. tmp/stylesheets).

However, when I reference stylesheets like so

> 

View-source reveals this incorrect path:

> href="/stylesheets/tmp/stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"

How do you set the default path to 'tmp/stylesheets' so I may simply type:

> screen %>

I followed everything here: [heroku development center - rails and compass](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-compass) and [Using Compass on Heroku: /tmp for stylesheets remotely and locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397533/using-compass-on-heroku-tmp-for-stylesheets-remotely-and-locally)

My Gist is here: https://gist.github.com/1156902

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can see a great screencast about that: [Railscasts #279 Understanding the Asset Pipeline](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline)

And here you can see how to change that path: [Asset Pipeline Rails Guide](http://ryanbigg.com/guides/asset_pipeline.html#changing-the-_assets_-path)

I believe that can help you

Comment: I am using Rails 3.0.7. I can't seem to find a solution for that.

Comment: can't you upgrade your rails? currently i'm using 3.0.9 without problems

Comment: I tried your suggestion and upgraded to 3.0.10 - the asset pipeline seems to be for rails 3.1, so I am still not achieving the desired results. I will continue to review. For instance I thought adding 'config.assets.prefix = /some_other_path'_ to application.rb would work but I got a compiler error.