# rails3 with compass-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, compass-sass

I'm trying to set up a rails 3.2 app with the new compass-rails gem

https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails

I want to compile the files in the assets folder with the compass watch command—as I want to deploy to heroku, but so far i'm unsuccessful.

The compass-rails gem page states:

> Developing with the Compass watcher
>
> When using the Compass watcher to update your stylesheets, your stylesheets are recompiled as soon as you save your Sass files. In this mode, compiled stylesheets will be written to your project's public folder and therefore will be served directly by your project's web server -- superceding the normal rails compilation.
>
> In this mode, rails 3.0 or earlier users will experience a slight speed up by disabling the Sass::Plugin like so:

```
config.after_initialize do
  Sass::Plugin.options[:never_update] = true
end
```

But i don't get where to put this config options

Any idea?

==EDIT==

I tried to add the config.after_initialize block in  my application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# require 'rails/all'
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
# require "sprockets/railtie"


if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module Salsacaribecouk
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]


    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

    config.after_initialize do
      Sass::Plugin.options[:never_update] = true
    end
  end
end
```

but when i run the rails server I get an error message:

`block in <class:Application>': uninitialized constant Sass::Plugin (NameError)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `config.after_initialize` should be put in `config\application.rb` if you want it to be executed in all environments, or in  `config\environments\[development|test|production].rb` to executed in a specific environment.

Comment: Do i put it in the module myapp \r class application < rails::application ?

Comment: yes, at the same level as the other `config.XXX` instructions

Comment: tried that but i get an error message, sass::plugin unitialized constant

Comment: Look at the answer of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300815/rails-3-0-turn-compass-sass-off-in-production-stylesheets-404 , it may help.